# How can I prevent the asset pipeline from conflicting with my /.../.../.../images URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, asset-pipeline

I have a REST API being served by Rails which has a path /api/blah/blah/images.json, which gives information about an image, which is an instance of an Image model.  In development, this works fine; in a sandbox environment we created, this gives an apache error (the path is never matched against routes.rb, and the rails log doesn't note the request at all).

We played around and found that this problem occurs for exactly those URLs which contain the substring "/images", "/javascripts", or "/stylesheets", so we suspect that the rails assets pipeline is somehow intercepting these URLs (and then not finding any image at that path, and giving an error).

How do you configure which URLs are treated as assets and which are passed to controllers according to routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  We had the following lines in our {environment}.include apache conf file:

```
# Turn passenger off for directories w/ just static content and
# allow auto indexing.
<Location ~ /(stylesheets|javascripts|images|snapshots|fonts)>
  PassengerEnabled off
  FileETag None
  # Options -Indexes
</Location>
```

This was turning off passenger (and therefore preventing Rails from ever getting the request) whenever the url path matched the regex `/\/(stylesheets|javascripts|images|snapshots|fonts)/`.  This is an extremely overzealous regex - in our case, it should really only match when the path starts with one of these names, so we changed it to

```
# Turn passenger off for directories w/ just static content and
# allow auto indexing.
<Location ~ ^/(stylesheets|javascripts|images|snapshots|fonts)/>
  PassengerEnabled off
  FileETag None
  # Options -Indexes
</Location>
```

so that it will only match when that word is actually the first thing in the path.